# WordPress Hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

How does WordPress implement hooks internally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, it maintains a global variable called `$wp_filter` to hold relevant data. Plugins can use functions like `add_filter()` to get themselves registered.

At various points (the hook points), wordpress examines `$wp_filter` to see if there are filters to run.

The easiest way to figure it out is to take a look at `wp-includes/plugin.php` and study the code there (or hook up a debugger and step through it, or set up `firePHP` and periodically dump stuff out)

I'm no expert, but I was curious, so I took a peek.  If I really wanted to know more, I'd do what I just suggested.

Comment: Just to note, the format of $wp_filters has changed a few times (and the variable name has too), so you should always use the API functions.

Answer (score 0):

if you have experience with any event driven programming like .net etc .. u must be aware of events .. consider these hooks as events as well ... a plugin registers the events it want to fire a function on and the event object remembers that .. and then when that event is fired from somewhere in WP .. it goes through the array to find the functions which it needs to call for that specific event.